# How can I inherit module in ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I have a hierarchy like

ABC(Folder) ---->  abc.rb, def.rb

DEF(Folder) ---->  a1.rb, b1.rb

GHI(Folder) ---->  x1.rb, y1.rb

I want to inherit/include def.rb, which is a module into abc.rb and then a1 should inherit abc.rb and should be able to access all methods defined in def.rb.

Right now, I am including def.rb in every script file, but I don't want to do this. I just want to inherit vertically.

Comment: What problems do you have? If you want to include some module into another module you just use `require`/`require_relative` (the last one is only for Ruby 1.9) to "see" your module definition and then simply call `include ModuleName`. It's hard to tell what troubles can this cause.

Comment: i have 10 module which i need to include in 10 other script so i was thinking if i include all of them in 1 script and than just include that script to next one it will be easy for me. so do we have any way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to deal with ABC-like naming system )

If you want to include 10 modules in each of your classes, you can do it this way. Let's imagine you have modules `ModuleTest::Files` and `ModuleTest::Network`:

**in module_test/network.rb**

```
module ModuleTest
    module Network
        def network
            puts 'hello from ModuleTest::Network#network'
        end
    end
end
```

**in module_test/files.rb**

```
module ModuleTest
    module Files
        def files
            puts 'hello from ModuleTest::Files#files'
        end
    end
end
```

You can make some `ModuleTest::Base` class like this:

```
require 'module_test/files'
require 'module_test/network'

module ModuleTest
    class Base
        include Files
        include Network
    end
end
```

This class includes all the functionality you have, so inherit your classes from it:

```
require 'module_test/base'

class Foo < ModuleTest::Base 
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.network
foo.files
```

Output:

```
>ruby -I. foo.rb
hello from ModuleTest::Network#network
hello from ModuleTest::Files#files
```

Answer (score 0):

Let my first point out that I suspect that I'm misinterpreting your question, because I can't see why you'd want to do this. So if that's the case, please point it out and I'll delete this.

The process you describe works (at least for me in Ruby 1.9.3).

```
module Def
  def method_from_def
    puts "Method from Def"
  end
end

class Abc
  include Abc
end

class X < Abc
end

X.new.method_from_def #=> "Method from Def"
```

You might need to be a little specific in your require statements, but if you're already able to 'include' the script you've already got that down. (Unless by 'include' you mean copy and paste it into the source file.)